# SharePoint 2010 subsetting a list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a long list with many contributors in SharePoint and I want to be able to edit items by searching for a short list of IDs. For example, I have IDs 1-1000 and I want to edit (in datasheet) items 1,4,35,36,37,88,497,512,800. Is there a way to do this kind of filtering?

Comment: I figured out how to do this with connected web parts, sort of. I have a list view web part that is providing filter data to another list view web part, but the filtered list is only displaying one row (the 'left' selected row) at a time. I would like to enter 5 values in the left list and see all 5 of those in the right list. Possible?

Comment: Are the item IDs arbitrary or is there some single value (perhaps in a new field if necessary) you could use to filter the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can link your list with an Excel file and filter in Excel if easier. Otherwise it's possible writing custom code, but not out of the box.